# How to handle SQL Server NULL values

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to get values from my database, it works when all columns have values. When a value is `NULL`, it returns an error.

I've managed to find a way to handle with the strings but if there's an integer I don't know how to handle it. I've tried to find a solution but none has worked for me so far! Here's the code, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    coments comentsar = new coments
            {
                Id = (int)dr["Id"],
                Name = (string)dr["Name"],
                Likes = (int)dr["Likes"],
          //    Signature = dr["Signature"].ToString(),
                Datetime = (DateTime)dr["Datetime"]
            };

    comen.Add(comentsar);

    return comen;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for null value and if the value is not null assign the variable using ternary operator:

```
Signature  = dr["Signature"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)dr["Signature"] : "No value",
Likes = dr["Likes"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["Likes"]) : 0,
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your types to `Nullable` types.

Change `(int)dr["Likes"]` to `(int?)dr["Likes"]`
and `Datetime = (DateTime)dr["Datetime"]` to `Datetime = (DateTime?)dr["Datetime"]`.

You will also need to update your model `coments` to allow for nullable types.

[Microsoft Nullable Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

Comment: Okay, ye i changed it to (int?)dr["Likes"] and In the coments model it looks like this public int? Likes { get; set; } im kinda new with this sorry but im not sure how to allow for null in the coments model

Comment: You've done it by changing comments to `public int? Likes { get; set; } ` :)

Comment: You can't cast `DBNull.Value` to nullable variable.